# Is it possible to run Azure Service Fabric Mesh on-premises?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Azure Service Fabric [can be run on Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server). Can Service Fabric Mesh be hosted that way as well?

Comment: Roadmaps are not something discussed here.

Comment: thanks, I'll remove the roadmap part from my question

Answer (score 1):

The underline platform is the same service fabric binaries, the only difference is that on MESH you don't manage nodes and all definitions is based on Containers and Hardware Resources (Network, CPU, storage), you will be able to simulate a "Single Node" MESH cluster like you do with current SF and deploy you mesh applications in there.

If your plan is to have a production environment onPrem I haven't got in much details about it, now that it is becoming an opensource solution, I assume yes, but I don't think it is on their top priority.

For now, there is not much documentation about it, so the best you can find will be on these links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric-mesh/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-service-fabric-mesh-is-now-in-public-preview/

How to setup local development cluster:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-howto-setup-developer-environment-sdk